# how to ask if @user.photo exists? created from (class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

My `User` model uses carrierwave to create images which are accessed as `@user.photo.thumb`. This is not a Photo model, `photo` is a `string column` in `User`. However, some users will not have uploaded a `photo`, so I want to create an `if/else` statement that will tell me whether they have uploaded a photo or not.

`<% if @user.photo %>` returns **true** even though the user has not yet uploaded a photo.

<% if @user.photo.nil? %> return **false**, however in Heroku console, it shows `column photo` as `nil` for that `user`.

> u = User.find(5) 
>   => User id: 5, name: "SpongeBob ",..., photo: nil>

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end

class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [150,150]
  end

  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

This is for use as an avatar. I want a default avatar image if they have not uploaded their own photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at the readme, you can just override the default_url in your uploader like so.   So if there is no picture, it will show default.

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url(*args)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end
end
```

This is if you are using the asset pipepline in your model

if you want to see if the file exists you need to do

```
@user.photo.file.nil?
```

Since that will check for the file actually existing.

Comment: `exists?` does not work but `@user.photo.file.nil?` does. Thanks.

Comment: hmm was doing it from memory, sigh.. Updated to be .nil?,  takeaway is that photo has been replaced by the uploader, so you need to dig into it to get what you are looking for, as it isn't just the plain field/string from the DB.